# Error: (repmgr) server is in standby mode and cannot be registered as a primary

Tags: postgresql, repmgr

I tried to follow this link: https://repmgr.org/docs/current/repmgr-primary-register.html

and run this command:

```
repmgr primary register --force --dry-run
```